# How do I count number of words in a string in Typescript without counting extraneous spaces?

Tags: string, typescript

I have seen many cases where people sometimes rely on whitespaces which causes some miscalculations.

For Example, take 2 strings;

```
const str1: string = 'I love stackoverflow'
const str2: string = 'I   love   stackoverflow'
```

Using the `numOfWhitespaces + 1` thing gives wrong number of words in case of `str2`. The reason is obvious that it counts 6 number of spaces.

So what should be an easy and better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest would be using: `str1.split(/\s+/).length`

But just in case any beginner want to do it with basic loop, here it is:

```
let str1: string = 'I love stackoverflow'
let numberOfSpaces: number = 0

for (let index = 1; index <= str1.length; index++) {
    let lastChar: string = ''
    let currentChar: string = ''
    currentChar = str1.charAt(index)
    lastChar = str1.charAt(index - 1)
    if (currentChar === " " && lastChar !== " ") {
        numberOfSpaces = numberOfSpaces+ 1
    }
    else if (currentChar === " " && lastChar === " ") {    // This is a test String.
        numberOfSpaces = numberOfSpaces + 0
    }
    //I have not added an else statement for the case if both current char and last char are not whitespaces.
    //because I felt there was no need for that and it works perfectly.
}

const finalNumberOfWords: number = numberOfSpaces + 1
console.log(`Number of words final are = ${finalNumberOfWords}`)
```

So this might look similar to the counting whitespaces method, yes it is but this one doesn't count the extraneous spaces [space followed by a space].
A `for loop` runs throughout the length of the string. It compares the character at current position of `str1[index]`and its previous index. If both are whitespaces, it won't count but if previous character was non-null and current is blank, it increments the counter by one.

And finally we add 1 to the counter to display number of words.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `str1.split(/\s+/).length` that's all you need 

Comment: Okay, just thought this would be an easier alternative based on some logic and basic concept of loops.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use a regex:

```
const str2: string = 'I   love   stackoverflow'

console.log(str2.split(/\s+/).length);
```

This will ensure that multiple spaces will be splitted.

Test:

```js
console.log('I   love   stackoverflow'.split(/\s+/).length);


console.log('Ilovestackoverflow'.split(/\s+/).length);
```